# MySQL "start" fails in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I try to run the command:

`sudo systemctl start mysql`

And receive the following message:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Then when i type:

```
sudo systemctl status mysql.service
```

I get the following message:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-03-02 11:32:34 IST; 58s ago
    Process: 3383 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 02 11:32:34 avivilloz systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Mar 02 11:32:34 avivilloz systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Mar 02 11:32:34 avivilloz systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 02 11:32:34 avivilloz systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 02 11:32:34 avivilloz systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

I searched for hours and couldn't come with a solution... does anyone know what could be the error?

The only thing i did before that was to install mysql-server with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

I tried installing and reinstalling, updating and upgrading ubuntu, i'm not sure if this would help.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I just checked, and don't have the /var/lib/mysql directory in my computer. But i failed to get it by reinstalling mysql server/client.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed by "purging" every file related to mysql and reinstalling mysql-server:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue is raised b.c the server storage is full.
removing some logs and files solved and then restarting it solved the problem.

Comment: this. purging mysql logs cleared 30% of server space for me. PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;